# Jackson serialization to report list of fields that could not be serialized

Tags: java, jackson

I am wrapping legacy code with some REST/jackson capabilities. In particular let's say I have an interface called LegacyObject

```
interface LegacyObject {
   Integer getAge(); //could throw UnsupportedOperationException
   String getDesc();
   String getName(); //May throw RuntimeException
   //about 200+ other methods.
}
```

The implementation is a legacy class and assume cannot be changed. My REST service has an endpoint which converts LegacyObject to JSON. The only problem being that this *conversion* fails fully whenever one of the getters throws an exception. What I need is a json like the below (assuming getAge(), getDesc() worked okay but getName() threw runtimeexception)

```
{"age": 40, "desc": "some description", "unsupportedFields": ["name"]}
```

Basically a way to capture all fields that failed serialization and then report at the end.

An interceptor like thing might work for me but if anyone has some code examples that would be great!

Comment: Why does an accessor `throws` exceptions?

Comment: Like I said the implementation is part of Legacy code. Before refactoring this I am attempting to *prove* that the REST service works. What I don't want is to fail the full method and end up sending status 500 to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are 200+ methods in the interface, below a solution with Proxies.

This code does not guarantee that the "getUnsupportedFields" method is called last (and thus still some exceptions may occur after)

```
public interface LegacyObject {
   Integer getAge(); //could throw UnsupportedOperationException
   String getDesc();
   String getName(); //May throw RuntimeException
   //about 200+ other methods.
}
```

```
import java.util.List;

public interface ExtendedLegacyObject extends LegacyObject {
    List<String> getUnsupportedFields();
}
```

```
public class ExceptionLegacyObject implements LegacyObject {
    @Override
    public Integer getAge() {
        return 40;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDesc() {
        return "some description";
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LegacyObjectHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LegacyObjectHandler.class);

    private final List<String> unsupportedFields = new ArrayList<>();

    private final LegacyObject legacyObject;

    public LegacyObjectHandler(LegacyObject legacyObject) {
        this.legacyObject = legacyObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if ("getUnsupportedFields".equals(method.getName())) {
            return unsupportedFields;
        } else {
            try {
                return method.invoke(legacyObject, args);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                Throwable cause = e.getCause();
                LOG.error(cause.getMessage(), cause);
                unsupportedFields.add(method.getName());
                Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
                if (returnType.isPrimitive()) {
                    if (returnType.isAssignableFrom(boolean.class)) {
                        return false;
                    } else if (returnType.isAssignableFrom(byte.class)) {
                        return (byte) 0;
                    } else if (returnType.isAssignableFrom(short.class)) {
                        return (short) 0;
                    } else if (returnType.isAssignableFrom(int.class)) {
                        return 0;
                    } else if (returnType.isAssignableFrom(long.class)) {
                        return 0L;
                    } else if (returnType.isAssignableFrom(float.class)) {
                        return 0F;
                    } else if (returnType.isAssignableFrom(double.class)) {
                        return 0D;
                    } else if (returnType.isAssignableFrom(char.class)) {
                        return (char) 0;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class JacksonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ExceptionLegacyObject exceptionLegacyObject = new ExceptionLegacyObject();
        ExtendedLegacyObject proxy = (ExtendedLegacyObject) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                LegacyObject.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { ExtendedLegacyObject.class },
                new LegacyObjectHandler(exceptionLegacyObject)
        );
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(proxy));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another approach with proxies in case you have 200+ methods, give me some time to work out the other approach

Comment: Indeed the above would be sub-optimal as there are 200+ methods. You have raised an interesting solution with Proxy which is definitely worth pursuing! If there is an elegant Jackson Interceptor that would have been perfect

Comment: It seems you can control the order in which Jackson serializes the properties with @JsonPropertyOrder, to ensure the "unsupportedFields" property comes last.  Having to define the order of 200+ properties explicitly   though is not an elegant solution

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can see you have handled primitives too (luckily I don't have to deal with it) but a better way to deal with primitives is to use Google's `Defaults` class

Answer (score 0):

I used a variation of what @toongeorges suggested above. Here is a utility class which will do a "exception safe" convert to JSON. There will be an extra element in the returned JSON called "exceptionMessages" which contains the properties that failed json serialisation (or the method name if it is NOT a Java bean property). This can be changed to return a Pair of JsonNode one for the object and one for exceptionMessages if that style suits you better

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;

public abstract class JsonUtils {
  private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  /**
   * This is only useful in the context of converting a object whose methods could throw exceptions
   * into JSON. By default a "getName" method that throws an exception will fail the whole
   * serialization however with this method such exceptions will be swallowed and there will be a
   * "exceptionMessages" element in the returned JSON which contains all failures
   *
   * To be used only when working with legacy code.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <U> ObjectNode exceptionSafeWrite(Class<U> sourceClazz, U obj, boolean prettyPrint) {
    GuardedInvocationHandler handler = new GuardedInvocationHandler(obj);
    U proxiedObject = (U) Proxy
        .newProxyInstance(sourceClazz.getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{sourceClazz}, handler);

    ObjectNode originalNode = mapper.convertValue(proxiedObject, ObjectNode.class);
    ObjectNode exceptionMessages = mapper.convertValue(handler.getExceptionMessagesForJson(), ObjectNode.class);
    originalNode.put("exceptionMessages", exceptionMessages);
    return originalNode;
  }


  private static class GuardedInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    private final Object target;
    private Map<Method, Throwable> exceptionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private Map<Method, String> methodToPropertyNameMap;

    private GuardedInvocationHandler(Object target) {
      this.target = target;
      this.methodToPropertyNameMap = methodToPropertyNameMap(target.getClass());
    }

    private static Map<Method, String> methodToPropertyNameMap(Class<?> clazz) {
      try {
        return Stream.of(Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz).getPropertyDescriptors())
            .collect(toMap(d -> d.getReadMethod(), d -> d.getName()));
      } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
      try {
        return method.invoke(target, args);
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        exceptionMap.put(method, e.getTargetException());
        return null;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        exceptionMap.put(method, e);
        return null;
      }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getExceptionMessagesForJson() {
      return exceptionMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
          toMap(e -> methodToPropertyNameMap.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), e.getKey().getName()),
              e -> ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e.getValue())));
    }
  }
}
```